# Password, salt, hash, DB: For the millionth time

Tags: database, hash, passwords

I know this topic has been discussed a million times. But it's new to me and the more I read about it the less I understand what's actually happening or supposed to happen.

I add a per-user salt to the hashed storage of a user's password, so the stored password hash looks like this: hash(password + perusersalt).
This results in same passwords of different users being stored as different strings in the DB. Cool. But I'm not worried about someone breaking into the DB and looking up the hashed passwords. I'm worried about someone brute-force-querying my server for combinations of username and password. In this case the salted and hashed storage of passwords is useless, because the correct combination of username and password will yield a successful login. Right?

Am I correct under the impression that in this scenario the salt is pretty useless? Because the server only accepts username and password at the interface (no salt transmitted), a normal dictionary attack will do, right?

So the salt is only there to obfuscate the password of a user (obtainable only by reverse Rainbow Table lookup) from someone who has access to the DB. Hmm.

Related: My web app doesn't even transmit plain passwords. Passwords are already hashed client side, only to entirely reject responsibility about someone's stolen passwords, and the whole thing uses SSL.

Does this mean I'm more or less at the highest possible security level, because correct combinations of username and password must of course yield a successful login?

Thank you for clearing up the mess in my head.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your assumption about the brute force attack. If the user has a simple password, the salt and hash won't really matter. The dictionary attack will guess "password" and allow the attacker in. You have to require a secure password from the user, then do the one-way encryption (hash it with the salt), and use SSL like you are.

Comment: If you control the web frontend, you can artificially limit the amount of passwords that can be tried per minute, and add a captcha image that other sites like hotmail use after some invalid tries to slow them down.

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS solution, you can usually control this even if you don't control the web side of the equation, but chances are it won't be very portable should you decide to switch to a new DB.

Comment: You could also use bcrypt, which is specifically designed to be slow and make brute-forcing slow regardless of how fast your server is.

Comment: I'm personally a big fan of Whirlpool with PHP. I used it for a corporate website and found it to be really easy to implement, and also very secure. It's obscure enough to not get the hacking attention of SHA, but it also quick.

Comment: Just one quick note: Please remember that hashing is not encryption as you stated here. It is a simple algorithmic obfuscation. Encryption requires a key.

Answer (score 0):

"Passwords are […] hashed client side […] to […] reject responsibility about someone's stolen passwords, and the whole thing uses SSL."

Does the client send hash(password+salt) ?

With this design, a client does not really need the password in order to login successfully, it only needs the hash. So you might still be responsible for leaking the *real password* (the hash).

Comment: The client sends a hashed password without any salt, unrelated to what is stored with salt in the DB. Transmission is secured with SSL.  The rejection of responsibility means with my hashed password accounts of same user with same passwords cannot be opened up elsewhere, a service to the user and increase of his privacy, and I can never be accused of doing wrong with user's clear passwords because I never received them. This is no security increase for my system (also no decrease), but very cool.

Comment: Even cooler: With a long enough fixed salt hard-wired into the client, readily available Rainbow Tables fail when the client already transmits hash(hardwiredsalt+plainpassword). The hashing methods used on my project are of course visible in the JavaScript (SHA-256 in this case) and this prevents hash collision with other sites coincidentally using the same method.